# mysql - strange thing with update and select statements

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a strange mysql-thing going on here, it is about the following code:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE group='".$group."'");
if (mysql_num_rows($res)==1) {

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
$uid = $row['uid'];

$user_update = mysql_query("UPDATE fe_users SET group = 5 WHERE  group='".$group."'");           

return 'ok';

} else {

return 'not ok';

}
```

I am checking, if there is a user with the `group = $group`. If so, the group is updated to 5 and after that the string "ok" is returned, if no user with `group=$group` exists, as you can see the string "not ok" is returned.

This should be very easy, but the problem now is, that if there is a user with `group=$group`, the update is done correctly, but instead of returning "ok", php returns "not ok", as if the change from the update is been taken into account for the above executed select retroactively. I dont understand this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanx in advance, 
Jayden

Comment: What is the context? Is this the code of a function ? Is this the code of an ajax response?

Comment: It is a function, no ajax and i built a scenario with no parameters, but still the same thing. If i remove the update-query from the if-part, all the other code within the if-part is executed correctly, but if the update-query is not removed, it is the only thing within the if-part that is executed and besides the query the else-part is executed.

Comment: It's very strange because the update-query is IN the if-statement and not in the else-statement. Can you step-by-step debug your code? If not, try putting a  `die('here')` after the update-statement and look if the function stop the execution.

Comment: thats a good idea, thank you for the input, alesdario. for the moment i have done a workaround for this because theres enough other stuff to do, but if maybe ive found out the reason for this behaviour, i gonna post it here. maybe its something very trivial...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 'group' is a reserved keyword that you have used as a field name, change it or use like

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group`='".$group."'");
```

and

```
$user_update = mysql_query("UPDATE fe_users SET `group` = 5 WHERE  `group`='".$group."'");
```

and you can use count($res)==1 instead of mysql_num_rows($res)==1 if it is a problem.

**Reference:** [Mysql Reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this has any merit but try using this style in your SELECT and UPDATE commands: WHERE group='$group', without using string joins. Other than that I can't seem to see why you are getting an update and not being returned "ok".

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `mysql_num_rows($res)==1`, so you'll return `ok` if there is exactly one user on that group. If there are two or more users, it will return `not ok`. Probably not what you want, right? I think you should check if `mysql_num_rows($res)>=1`.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider modifying the placement of your brackets, and changing your num_rows check, like so:

```
$res = mysqli_query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE `group` ='".$group."'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($res)>0) {//there was a result
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        // grab the user id from the row
        $uid = $row['uid'];
        // and update their record
        $user_update = mysqli_query("UPDATE fe_users SET `group` = 5 WHERE  `group`='".$group."'");           
        if(mysqli_num_rows($user_update)==1){
            return 'ok, updated user';
        } else {
        // database error
            return 'not ok, unable to update user record';
        }  
    }//end while row
}else{
    return 'No results were found for this group.';
}
```

By selecting just the column you want, you reduce the query's overhead.  By comparing the initial result to 0 instead of 1, you allow for groups with many members.  By wrapping the update function in a while loop, you can loop through all the returned results, and update records for each one.  By moving the test that returns 'ok'/'not ok' to check for success on the update operation, you're able to isolate database errors.  The final else statement tells you if no update operation was performed because there are no members of the group.

BTW, for future-compatible code, I recommend using mysqli, as the "mysql_query" family of PHP functions are officially deprecated.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php for a quick start, it's largely the same thing.